# scala function literal and methods and underscore

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a very simple piece of code that I am not able to get grasp of. I am reading function literals, and methods. I am doing this in repl.

```
scala> val v = (a:Int, b:Int, c:Int) => {a+b+c}
v: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = $$Lambda$1368/1731643198@4ae730ca

scala> val v1 = v(1,2,_:Int)
v1: Int => Int = $$Lambda$1369/903167315@93d6f4

scala> v1 (10)
res29: Int = 13

scala>

scala> val v2 = v _
v2: () => (Int, Int, Int) => Int = $$Lambda$1370/5485285@7dd5d17a

scala> val v3 = v2()
v3: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = $$Lambda$1368/1731643198@4ae730ca

scala> val v4 = v3(1,2,3)
v4: Int = 6

scala> def sumMe(a:Int, b:Int, c:Int) = { a+b+c}
sumMe: (a: Int, b: Int, c: Int)Int

scala> val v7 = sumMe _
v7: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = $$Lambda$1371/906350712@6c86938f

scala> v7(1,2,3)
res30: Int = 6
```

I need some help in understanding on what happens above. I will start from the bottom of the code. When I create the method sumMe and assign it to "v7" with "_" on the right, I know I am not executing the method. The output of `val v7= sumMe_` is quite clear to me as it simply tells me that v7 will take 3 params, and return an int. It feels OK so far.

Now when I go to my `val v1 = v(1,2,_:Int), I can still correlate that it will create a function object and assign to v1 and in fact I am using Scala
s Function1's apply method is what I view it as.

I am hoping I understand it right so far. If my understanding above is right, what causes the most confusion is `val v2 = v _`. And based on the output of what I see I have to call this thing differently. Basically I am not able to understand why v2 is different from v7. v2 takes no arguments and gives me a function which I can call. If that is always the case with function literals of the kind that I have defined as `val v = ...`, then when I do `val v1 = v(1,2,:_Int)` why don't I get this from scala `v1:()=>Int=>Int` which is similar to `v2's case`.

And lastly, why won't `v7=sumMe _` not give me the same output as `val v2 = v_`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala, we differentiate *methods* from *functions*. When you define `sumMe`, you're defining a method, while your other declarations are functions. Methods, in Scala, [are non value types](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#method-types), meaning the method itself has no value. When you try to assign it to a value, there is an implicit conversion called [eta expansion](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion) that is done to convert it to the corresponding function type. From the specification:

> Method types do not exist as types of values. If a method name is used
>   as a value, its type is implicitly converted to a corresponding
>   function type.

Now that we're equipped with the knowledge of methods and functions, lets analyze what happens.

> When I create the method `sumMe` and assign it to "v7" with "_" on the right, I know I am not executing the method

That's right. When you do `sumMe _`, you're using eta-expansion to convert the method to a function.

> Now when I go to my `val v1 = v(1, 2, _: Int)`, I can still correlate that
>   it will create a function object and assign to v1

Again, you're right. `v1` is now a partially applied function of type `Function1[Int, Int]`.

> Basically I am not able to understand why v2 is different from v7.

What is `v2`? It is a function object which was created by partially applying an existing function object. Since this function of type `Function3[Int, Int, Int, Int]` is already fixed in it's parameter list, partially applying it only nests it in another function object, now of type `Function0`, making it a `Function0[Function3[Int, Int, Int, Int]]`.

Comment: Hi Yuval, your explanation helps. I will come back on this and ask you a little more about it once I read your post over and over. Can you meanwhile try to explain a little more what you meant by the ending of your answer - Note the later is a special....
Are you saying I have a  build error in my code?

Comment: @curiousengineer I deleted that part as there seems to be an issue with the scope of declaration. You can do this on members of a class but not inside a method declaration, I'm working on figuring out the exact rules but they don't really matter for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Scala, functions are value that means you can assign any  function in a variable. Whenever you apply placeholder("_") in front of def it will convert def into function with same input and output types. If you apply placeholder in front of value it will convert into function that take  unit as input and return value as output**[() => T]**. for example:

```
 scala> val a = 2
 a: Int = 2

scala> val fun1  = a _
fun1: () => Int = <function0>

scala> def sum(a:Int, b:Int) = a+ b
sum: (a: Int, b: Int)Int

scala> val fun2 = sum _
fun2: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

whenever you are trying to pass partial input parameters in a "def" it will return **partial applied** function. For example:

```
scala> val fun3 = sum(1,_:Int)
fun3: Int => Int = <function1>
```

fun3 is called partial applied function.

Answer (score 1):

There are something need to clear for `function` and `method`,

1. **function**: we use `val` and `var` to define the `function`, it's often is an `Anonymous Function`, In **Scala**, there are `Function0`, `Function1`, `Function2` ... for these `Anonymous Function`, and the function type like: `(T0, T1...TN) => U`.

   > so **function** `v` actually is a `Function3` with **3** parameters.
2. **method**: it's used to `def` to declare with `method` body with the **parameters** and `return type`.

For `val v2 = v _` actually equals to `val v2 = () => v`, in there wildcard `_` will expand to `() => v`, and `v2` means it's a function to create another function(`v`) without parameter.So `val v3 = v2()` means `invoke v2()` to create `v` function, so essentially `v3` equal to `v`.

For `val v7 = sumMe _` this means **convert method** `sumMe` to a function, in there wildcard `_` will expand to `(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) => sumMe(a, b, c)` , so `sumMe _` will create a new function that's essentially equal to `v`, if you use `v7 _` it also will create the same `function` like `val v2 = v _`.

**Reference**:

[Difference between method and function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala)